# Writing to kubernetes parameter store from nodejs app

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

Am I wondering if there is a way to read and write to Kubernetes parameter store from a nodejs app?

I would like to persist/invalidate/refresh an access token and share it across multiple instances during runtime. Can't find any good docs on how to do it exactly.

Comment: Could you explain what you understand under "Kubernetes parameter store"? Do you mean the `etcd` that is used by Kubernetes?

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure of the terminology - I meant the https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/

Comment: Amazon provides the [AWS SDK for node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/), which also includes a class for [SecretsManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SecretsManager.html) that you can use, but I guess you are looking for a ready-made solution.

Comment: No, that's fine I will look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon provides the [AWS SDK for node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/), which also includes a class for [SecretsManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SecretsManager.html).